# Imagebeforetext does not center button contents

Tags: c#, winforms, button, alignment

I'm using Windows Forms.NET.

I've configured a button in the following way:

**ImageAlign**: MiddleCenter
**TextAlign**: MiddleCenter
**TextImageRelation**: ImageBeforeText

The problem is, when I make button wider than usual, its contents are no longer centered:

[image: Invalid button content rendering]

Why is it so? How can I correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the Text and Image share 2 even parts of the Button Client area horizontally. So if you set the TextImageRelation as OverLay, ImageAboveText, TextAboveImage  they should be what we expect. But for other values, they act differently. I think that's by design.

To solve your problem, I have tried changing ImageAlign to MiddleRight and it works as what you want.

Again, I think that's by design. :)

Comment: Ok, but what logic is behind this? Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: @Spook I'm not sure, maybe the designers know why it should be so. You can try changing the ImageAlign variously and see that's really by design. If I design the control myself, I may make it work differently (I like drawing stuff in customizing control :)